# Came across strange javascript while fixing a page

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a page that's been sabotaged by somebody and well that person added extra code. I have no clue what it does but i know it doesn't belong there.

I have included a link right here to pastebin [right here](http://pastebin.com/nzhm651W)

The code at the bottom of the page is strange (at line 130 till 179)... can someone explain it to me?

**Prolly should mention not to run this in any circumstances**

EDIT: I have jsbeautified it and put it [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fuMCmF6n)

Comment: It's an obfuscated script. No idea how to find out what it does.

Comment: Lines 21-26 look mighty suspicious as well.

Comment: I vote it an injects an `<iframe src="www.warez.com/hackyou">` into your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by [jsbeautifying](http://jsbeautifier.org/) the code, although that didn't help much. It's most likely some malicious code, but it could take a while to determine what it does.

If you are interested, the code is obfuscated, meaning it's made as hard as possible to comprehend what it does. Some people use this to hide source code, some use it to inject malicious code without showing what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The code is obfuscated and you can try to understand the intention by doing `unescape('\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74')` in javascript console which resolves to createElement.

Comment: That's interesting, is there more of these codes that seem like gibberish and resolve to something?

Comment: 100% of it that looks like gibberish likely resolves to actual code. The whole point is to hide the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be malicous code! Check your computer for malware etc.

Comment: Haha it actually wouldn't open at first because antivirus was killing it off. Someone managed to open it without triggering it